# Vue Composition API - getting a ref using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ref, vue-composition-api

Vetur is underlining null on this line below:

```
const firstRef = ref<HTMLElement>(null)
```

```
No overload matches this call.
 Overload 1 of 3, '(raw: HTMLElement): Ref', gave the following error.
  Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.
 Overload 2 of 3, '(raw: HTMLElement): Ref', gave the following error.
  Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.Vetur(2769)
```

Here's a condensed context. Any ideas what I did wrong?

```
<template>
  <input id="first" ref="firstRef">
  <button type="button" @click.prevent="focusFirst">Focus</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api"
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Test",
  setup() {
    const firstRef = ref<HTMLElement>(null)
    const focusFirst = () => {
      const theField = firstRef.value
      theField.focus()
    }

    return { focusFirst }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As given back by Vetur, you cannot convert a `null` type to an `HTMLELement` type. A possible way to fix this would be to write:

```
const firstRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
```

However, keep in mind that you'll have to check if `firstRef` is of type `null` every time you want to use it. You could do something like this as well:

```
if (firstRef.value) {
  // do stuff with firstRef
  // typescript knows that it must be of type HTMLElement here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but I had to use firstRef.value. If you update you answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm just getting started, so I'm not sure about the pros / cons, but it seems like you could use `const firstRef = ref<HTMLElement>()`, which would just make the ref `HTMLElement | undefined`, but it's a little shorter. Technically, you could also override the type system with something like `ref<HTMLElement>(null!)`, but that might be a bad idea since it can lead to unsafe usage before the ref is initialized (e.g. before the component is mounted).

Comment: It would work as well @jon_wu, however `undefined` means something different than `null` in javascript. I think `null`, by its definition, is better suited for this use case. Because `undefined` would imply that `firstRef.value` does not exist.

Comment: @Keimeno Totally agree `null` feels more correct and pure. Was just thinking that for some, they might prefer the brevity and potential readability of the more concise option. In practice, between `null | undefined | HTMLElement`, you may often just care about whether something is truthy, e.g. `if (firstRef.value)`.

Comment: With `HTMLElement` type, to access component methods is not allowed. Because component methods are not in the `HTMLElement` type

Comment: You can resolve this by casting the value to any or defining your own Interface with the element methods (which is time consuming but something I would advise). Anyway, here is a quick work around it.

- const firstRef: <HTMLElement | null) = ref(null);

- // to access methods or properties in it;
- (firstRef.value as unknown as any).method();

```

Answer (score 2):

```
const firstRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
```

will cause error when you try to access not only HTML props also vue component methods & props. So it will be better to use:

```
const myComponentRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>()
```

Referance: [Typing of component refs](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/402)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be optional chaining (since TS 3.7):

```
firstRef.value?.focus()
```

This will be fine for TS and execute the command only if `firstRef.value` is not null or undefined.